# How to fake device info for a specific app?

Tags: applications, ram

I need an app that can spoof device info. Like:

*Choose amount of RAM:* `20GB`

*Choose your CPU:* `ARM64 9000cores`

*Choose app to lie to:* `[android app]`

And so on.
I know there is an Xposed module for that, but I want to temporarily fake info for only one app of my choosing, and **not** permanently for the whole device.

I also know of the GLTools app, that lets you do exactly that, but because it's a GPU tweaking app, it wants me to install a custom EGL driver first, which I don't need.

I would prefer a non-root alternative, if such exists, but root ones are equally as welcome.

Comment: There is only one chance to get this without root: You have to [repackage the app and include the Frida Gadget in it](https://koz.io/using-frida-on-android-without-root/). Using this solution you could develop a Frida script that returns forged data for certain system information calls. If the app contains anti-reverse engineering and/or anti-debugging measures this can get pretty complicated.

Comment: Which is this Xposed module that can fake RAM?

Comment: I'm entirely unfamiliar with frida, and the question is about whether or not there is a "tap-and-go" app to do this

Comment: I noticed you've asked [a similar question on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581058). For Android, I don't think there is a "tap-and-go" app that can fake device info easily. While Robert's comment is a possible answer, I'm afraid this might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)...

Comment: Yeah, it's actually same app I want to run, BOINC, only this time for android. On my laptop, I did manage to fool it, works like a charm, and doesn't actually use as much memory as it claimed to need, which made me think, why not to try to do same thing on Android? And no, there IS one app that can do that, called GLTools, except it needs to install a special driver before I can use it, which I'm understandably hesitant about. So, if there is one app, why can't there be another?

Comment: Memory allocated to an app is determined by the Android Framework: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory#CheckHowMuchMemory `The exact heap size limit varies between devices based on how much RAM the device has available overall.` You are free to alter your own custom ROM but on a mobile device - swapping is bad and will burn out the lifetime of Flash memory. As GLTools provides a different graphics driver than what is built-in which allows for "fixes" to the OEM driver in a gaming context, I'm not sure how that relates to C/C++ apps running on CPU.

Comment: I don't want and don't need to mess with heap sizes. Swapping **was** bad, but now zRAM is enabled in every single android device by default. And while GLtools provided different graphics driver, it **also** provided the ability to spoof specs -- make an app think that you are using Google Pixel with 8GB RAM, when in fact you are using Huawei with 2GB. It didn't provide those additional 6GB in any way, no swapping involved. It just **lied**. And that's exactly what I need. But I don't need that EGL driver, and the app won't let me past start screen, unless I install it. So I need another app